# .NET Core 6 migration error: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim<string>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

After migrating a .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET Core 6, I receive the following error whenever my DbContext class is called:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim' since it is being used for entity type 'AspNetRoleClaims' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'IdentityRoleClaim' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'AspNetRoleClaims'.*

After much searching, I have been unable to find a solution to this issue. The code I used in 3.1 worked fine, so I can only assume something has changed between then and now. Here is the code for my db context:

```
public partial class MyProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public MyProjectContext()
    {
    }

    public MyProjectContext(DbContextOptions<MyProjectContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName, "RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserTokens>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName, "UserNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");
        });
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
    }
}
```

I have following from the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I have tried changing the class declaration to

```
public partial class IdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
```

and received the same error.

I have also tried the following to address the foreign key issue

```
public partial class IdentityDbContext<TUser>
    : IdentityDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>
        where TUser : IdentityUser
```

However, it results in a compiler error.

I have even tried stating the foreign key explicitly in the model declaration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);

                //Tried to declare the relationship here
                entity.HasOne(d => d.RoleId)
                    .WithOne(p => p.*) //compiler error regardless of entry
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.*) //compiler error regardless of entry
            });
```

Unsurprisingly, this didn't work either; I do not have any IdentityUser in my actual database.

So what am I missing here? I cannot find an easy way to troubleshoot this. It seems to trip the error the moment the Context class has finished processing, so that is where I suspect the problem may lie.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: Here is the IdentityUser class. It is the default included with the framework.

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The default implementation of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1 which
    //     uses a string as a primary key.
    public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        //     The user name.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser(string userName)
            : this()
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide listing of your `IdentityUser` class

Comment: Identity user class posted. It is the default class from the framework.

Answer (score 0):

The dotnet EF scaffold command doesn't map many to many tables in EF Core 6, see issue https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues/1191.
Use EFCorePowerTools instead and enable Many to Many on the Advanced options dialog resolves this.

Comment: I used EFCorePowerTools with the many-to-many advanced option checked. The code you are looking at in the problem is generated from the solution you have suggested, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET Core 6.0 and EF Core 6.0 (Adding Identity to existing database)

After looking through countless forums, tutorials, discussion pages and documentation, here's the YouTube video that finally helped me resolve this issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5X9ogJVWAjE&ab_channel=DataVids

Essentially, you should have a DbContext file that was provided from Identity (we'll call Id_DbContext) that inherits from IdentityDbContext. This will be used to build the identity tables in the database. Your existing DbContext file (we'll call Existing_DbContext) will inherit from Id_DbContext and will have everything in there from your existing database.

/////////Identity Context File Class Header////////////////

```
public class Id_DbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

/////////Existing Context File Class Header////////////////

```
public partial class Existing_DbContext : Id_DbContext
```

Hope this helps and saves you some hours of searching for a solution. .NET Core 6.0 and EF Core 6.0 are relatively new so there's not a lot of online support available just yet.

Good luck!